# vi input mode in R?

Tags: r, command-line, history, vi

I'd like to be able to edit my R history using vi commands (e.g. ESC-/, ESC-k).  I noticed a similar question here:
[vi input mode in command line Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380577/vi-input-mode-in-command-line-matlab)
and tried the readline mods suggested in this post (doesn't R use readline?) but they don't work (for me).

Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  I use vi commands in *nix without issue.

Comment: The .inputrc trick only works when launching R from the command line and not when clicking the icon that launches the GUI.

Comment: `.inputrc` doesn't seem to work for me on OS X.  For example, hit escape and press `0` does not send one to the beginning of the line among other things.  Works fine on bash, ipython and psql though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Vim-R-plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) should do the trick. I have used it in Ubuntu, MacOS, and Windows 7. The developer is great and does frequent bugfixes.

To get Vim behavior in the R console you'll need to use the [Conque Shell plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771), which Vim-R-plugin supports. I tried it for a day but found modality in the R command line a little tedious. All I ever use is tab completion and last command.