# How can I get native Vi mode in R to be persistent?

Tags: r, vim, readline

I have looked at the answers to [vi input mode in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606463/vi-input-mode-in-r) and [vi mode to emacs mode while on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399874/vi-mode-to-emacs-mode-while-on-r). Through the latter question, I learned that  `meta-ctrl-j` will work to toggle `vi-mode` in R, but I cannot get it to stick so that every time I start `R`, vi-mode is enabled by default.

I have tried placing `set editing-mode vi` in my `.inputrc`, but that does not have the desired effect.

How can I get the `vi-mode` from `meta-ctrl-j` to be persistent across `R` sessions?

Comment: The question is about native Vi-mode in R, which is related to the readline library, but I was hoping R users might know.

Comment: Is your .inputrc file in $HOME? `system("echo $HOME")` # for me=
/Users/davidwinsemius

Comment: `set editing-mode vi` works for me.

Comment: @graywh, I think there is some other setting that is overriding that for me, but I never found out what it was.

Comment: More information about your system would help.  Is this linux?  Are you starting R from the command line?  Are your command line commands in vi mode(i.e., if you press escape at the bash terminal, do you get into normal mode like you would in vi)?  I also have `set editing-mode vi` in my .bashrc but maybe that isn't necessary.  Anyway, like other commenters, it works for me.  I think you can get to the bottom of this if you keep trying.

Comment: @famsy, Yes, this is running on Ubuntu 13.04 with R from the command line. This is a machine that I do not have root on, so there is a limit on what I can try. The same setting works fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bind -f ~/.inputrc` then `bind -V | grep editing-mode` and see if you get `editing-mode is set to 'vi'`.

If that works, it's just a matter of getting that file to be read on login.

Try `echo $INPUTRC`, if empty set it in your `~/.bashrc`. Bash will supposedly check for `~/.inputrc` then `$INPUTRC` then `/etc/inputrc` in search of your inputrc config.

Additionally, you might try adding `bind -f ~/.inputrc` to your `~/.bashrc` if `R` opens up an interactive shell.